# How to change the variables form environment to collection level in postman

Tags: postman

I want to move variables from environment to collection
level but i do not find import option in collection level, please advise.

Comment: There isn't currently an import option specifically for the collection variables as those would be brought in when Importing the collection.

Answer (score 1):

I exported the environment variables then opened the JSON file split screen and copy/pasted the values into the collection variables. Not the best approach and you will need to remove the '' encoding for new line and quotations but was the quickest solution at the time. I then selected no environment to verify the collection requests ran correctly. Once verified remove the variables from the environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, recently--having to move a large number of environment variables to a collection.

Here's how I did it on Windows with Postman 8.9.0:

1. Export the environment to a JSON file.
2. Export the collection to a JSON file.
3. Load both files into Notepad++.
4. **Cut** the desired variable settings **from** the environment file "**values**" array property

```
{
    "id": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx....",
    "name": "MyEnvironment",
    "values": [
        {
            "key": "MyName",
            "value": "Darwin Mayflower",
            "enabled": true
        },
        {
            "key": "ProjectName",
            "value": "World Domination",
            "enabled": true
        },
        ...
    ],
    ...
}
```

5. and **paste** them to the **collection** file "**variable**" array property.

```
{
    "info": {
        "_postman_id": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx.........",
        "name": "My Collection",
        "schema": "https://schema.getpostman.com/json/collection/v2.1.0/collection.json"
    },
    ...
    "variable": [
        {
            "key": "MyName",
            "value": "Darwin Mayflower",
            "enabled": true
        },
        {
            "key": "ProjectName",
            "value": "World Domination",
            "enabled": true
        }
    ]
}
```

6. Save both files.
7. Delete the environment from Postman and import the environment JSON file.
8. Delete the collection from Postman and import the collection JSON file.

Worked like a charm!

Comment: This works well only when there's one environment, it doesn't allow having multiple environments (values) for the same variables and switching between them.